# why i cant print sentence and variable value in 1 line use python?

Tags: python, putty

Im try to calculating available subnet with python. just simple call but error.

```
    print ("the IP is valid")
    result = (2 ** (32 - int(mask)) - 2)
    print ("net available: ".format(result))
```

Comment: If you Google the phrase "Python print format", you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print ("the IP is valid")
result = (2 ** (32 - int(mask)) - 2)
print ("net avaiable: {0}".format(result))
```